# Button to find elements in an Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, find

I am trying to make a site where the user can hit a button and it will return data from the array.  For example, a button called 'show male dogs' should bring back the 3 male dogs in the array.

I am not seeing any errors, but nothing happens when I click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <body>  
  <main> 
   <br> <!-- ******************* Button *********************** -->
   <button onclick="showMales()"> # Show Male Dogs </button>
   <p id="btn"></p>

    <br> <!-- ******************* JS Code *********************** -->
    <script>
     const dogArray = [
      {Name: "Boris", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Labrador", Link:    "Boris.html"},
      {Name: "Lucy", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Lucy.html"},
      {Name: "Daisy", Gender: "Female", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Daisy.html"}, 
      {Name: "Honey", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Honey.html"}, 
      {Name: "Harley", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Labrador", Link: "Haryley.html"}, 
      {Name: "Dolly", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Dolly.html"},
      {Name: "Max", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Max.html"}, 
      {Name: "Birdie", Gender: "Female", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Pregnant Hog", Link: "Birdie.html"}, 
      ];

      function showMales(dog) {
      return dog.Gender === "Male";
      }

      console.log(dogArray.find(showMales));
    </script>
 </main>           
</body>
```

Comment: You have defined `dog` as a parameter for `showMales()`, but you don't pass in any arguments when it's executed when the button is clicked. You should see an error in your developer console when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

You could try filter the result first before printing it, something like this:

```
 const maleDogs = dogArray.filter(dog => dog.Gender === "Male");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the filter function instead of the find. The find function should return the first match while filter get all the records matched with the condition

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <body>  
  <main> 
   <br> <!-- ******************* Button *********************** -->
   <button onclick="showMales()"> # Show Male Dogs </button>
   <ul id="list"></ul>

    <br> <!-- ******************* JS Code *********************** -->
    <script>
     const dogArray = [
      {Name: "Boris", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Labrador", Link:    "Boris.html"},
      {Name: "Lucy", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Lucy.html"},
      {Name: "Daisy", Gender: "Female", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Daisy.html"}, 
      {Name: "Honey", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Honey.html"}, 
      {Name: "Harley", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Labrador", Link: "Haryley.html"}, 
      {Name: "Dolly", Gender: "Female", Age: "Puppy", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Dolly.html"},
      {Name: "Max", Gender: "Male", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Golden Retriever", Link: "Max.html"}, 
      {Name: "Birdie", Gender: "Female", Age: "Senior", Breed: "Pregnant Hog", Link: "Birdie.html"}, 
      ];

      function showMales() {
        const listDogs = document.getElementById('list');
        listDogs.innerHTML = '';
        var dogs = dogArray
          .filter(dog => dog.Gender === "Male")
          .map(dog => {
            let listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.textContent = dog.Name;
            listDogs.appendChild(listItem);
            return dog;
          });
        console.log(dogs);
      }
    </script>
 </main>           
</body>
```

Comment: ok, i see where 'filter' is better than 'find' for this function.  but i have 2 follow-up questions for you . . .                                                                                                        (1) do i have to make it iterative?  like "for (i = 0; i < dogArray.length; ++i) { document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = (dogArray[Male]);" ?                         (2) what do you mean by 'publish the list'?  do you mean i should use 'console.log' or something similar?                                             P.S. I am new to development, so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Hi @MaureenFlannery, got it. IMHO, there are some ways to display the list on the UI. I just updated the code to display the name of the dogs in a list.  
Basically I put a nested map in the same time that we are filter the dogs and pushing every dog filtered in the listDogs. 

Please check it and let me know if it's more clear :)